# Select Cells to End of Notebook

Tags: front-end, customization, keyboard

I'd like to create a keyboard shortcut that will allow me to select all of the cells from the current cell until the end of the notebook, similar to how <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>End</kbd> functions when editing text in most Windows applications.

By editing `KeyEventTranslations.tr`, I've already created a shortcut using <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> that allows me to select the current cell (rather then pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> repeatedly).  I'd like to then use another shortcut that would allow me to avoid having to hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and press <kbd>↓</kbd> over and over until I reach the bottom.

Any ideas?

Comment: I seem to recall that a simpler question, selecting multiple cells, had no forthcoming answer.  I hope this proves possible but I'm doubtful.  EDIT: docs for `SelectionMove` confirm: "SelectionMove can only select multiple cells as part of a CellGroup unit specification."

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it
too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) [`Read the FAQs`](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)!  3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking 
the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system 
is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to 
accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Building on Albert's answer I added code such that Ctrl Shift End will select all cells downwards.
Just execute this code in a notebook and restart Mathematica:

```
   mymenuitems="
         (* Select all cells downwards *)
         Item[KeyEvent[\"End\", Modifiers -> {Control, Shift}], 
         KernelExecute[
          Module[{ enb = EvaluationNotebook[],
                   tag = StringJoin[\"tmp\", ToString[Round[AbsoluteTime[]/$TimeUnit]]],editable 
                   },
                editable = ReplaceAll[Editable, Options[enb, Editable]];
                SetOptions[enb, Editable -> False];
                SelectionMove[enb, Next, Cell, AutoScroll -> False];
                MathLink`CallFrontEnd[FrontEnd`SelectionAddCellTags[enb, {tag}]];
                SelectionMove[enb, After, Notebook, AutoScroll -> False];
                SelectionMove[enb, Previous, Cell, AutoScroll -> False];
                While[FreeQ[ReplaceAll[CellTags,Options[NotebookSelection[]]], tag],
                      MathLink`CallFrontEnd[FrontEnd`SelectionAddCellTags[enb, {tag}]];
                      SelectionMove[enb, Previous, Cell, AutoScroll -> False]
                ];
                NotebookFind[enb, tag, All, CellTags, AutoScroll -> False];
                MathLink`CallFrontEnd[FrontEnd`SelectionRemoveCellTags[enb, {tag}]];
                SetOptions[enb, Editable -> editable]
            ]
            ], MenuEvaluator -> Automatic ]
            ";
    Quiet@CreateDirectory@FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory,"SystemFiles","FrontEnd","TextResources",$OperatingSystem}];
    mykeyeventtrans=FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory,"SystemFiles","FrontEnd","TextResources",$OperatingSystem,"KeyEventTranslations.tr"}];
    If[FileExistsQ[mykeyeventtrans],DeleteFile@mykeyeventtrans];
    CopyFile[FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory,"SystemFiles","FrontEnd","TextResources",$OperatingSystem,"KeyEventTranslations.tr"}],mykeyeventtrans];
keytext=Import[mykeyeventtrans,"Text"];
mykeytext=StringReplace[keytext,"EventTranslations[{":>StringJoin["EventTranslations[{\n(* User defined *)\n",mymenuitems,",\n"]];
Export[mykeyeventtrans,mykeytext,"Text"];
```

I only tested this on Windows. No idea if it works on MacOSX and Linux.

Answer (score 3):

I also don't know a straightforward way to do what you want, so Mr.Wizard could well be right. But there are workarounds as e.g. the following which is "abusing" `CellTags`. It is however somewhat hacky and not very fast and reliable and I'm not sure whether it is good enough for your every day use:

```
Module[{
  enb = EvaluationNotebook[],
  tag = StringJoin[
    RandomChoice[
     Join[CharacterRange["A", "Z"], CharacterRange["a", "z"], 
      CharacterRange["0", "9"]],
     30]
    ],
    editable
  },
 editable = Editable /. Options[enb,Editable];
 SetOptions[enb, Editable -> False];
 SelectionMove[enb, Next, Cell, AutoScroll -> False];
 MathLink`CallFrontEnd[FrontEnd`SelectionAddCellTags[enb, {tag}]];
 SelectionMove[enb, After, Notebook, AutoScroll -> False];
 SelectionMove[enb, Previous, Cell, AutoScroll -> False];
 While[FreeQ[CellTags /. Options[NotebookSelection[]], tag],
  MathLink`CallFrontEnd[FrontEnd`SelectionAddCellTags[enb, {tag}]];
  SelectionMove[enb, Previous, Cell, AutoScroll -> False];
  ];
 NotebookFind[enb, tag, All, CellTags, AutoScroll -> False];
 MathLink`CallFrontEnd[FrontEnd`SelectionRemoveCellTags[enb, {tag}]];
 SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], Editable -> editable]
 ]
```

It should be relatively clear what this does, nevertheless I think some remarks might be helpful:

- I'm using a random tag to mark the cells to be selected (a common strategy to create 
  global unique identifiers GUIDs), you could probably think of something smarter and 
  e.g. check whether the tag you want to use is already present in the notebook to be on 
  the really save side. I think it would, for almost all use cases, also be good enough 
  to work with a constant unique identifier, though...
- to temporarily add tags without destroying already existing ones, I'm using the 
  undocumented frontend functionality `SelectionAddCellTags` and 
  `SelectionRemoveCellTags` which I know from the excellent talk "The joy of Tagging" 
  given by David Reiss at a Wolfram User Conference some years ago. You should be able to 
  find the corresponding notebook in the web which is a good read if you try to do 
  any kind of advanced notebook manipulating...
- except for the random tag generation it should be possible to do this completely in the 
  frontend which might be a good idea if you want it to be executed from a keyboard 
  shortcut or button.
- as suggested by Rolf Mertig I did set the notebook to not be editable while the code is 
  running so that it should be relatively safe against user input.
- there might well be other features, especially undocumented ones, which might let you 
  do the same thing more reliable and faster, so don't accept this answer too early...

Comment: it is easy to secure against user input. Just add SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], Editable -> False]; at the beginning of the Module and SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], Editable -> True] at the end

Comment: @RolfMertig: good point, I have incorporated it ...

Comment: I changed the tag to  ToString @ Round @ AbsoluteTime[] . Or is there any good argument not to do so?

Comment: Why is `SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], Editable -> False]` the last thing to be evaluated?

Comment: @acl: because I didn't test it :-). Of course it should have been set to `True`. Actually it would be even better to set it to the value it had before we changed it, which I have now inserted...

Comment: @RolfMertig: I don't see any reason to not use `ToString@Round@AbsoluteTime[]`. We just need a string which is different from any of the `CellTags` that are contained in the notebook we are editing. Both of these approaches will be 'almost always' correct, which I think will be good enough. There are possibilities to get a list of existing `CellTags` as described in David's talk, so we could even crosscheck whether what we did choose really doesn't exist yet. And I think that such a check would even be very fast compared to the rest of the code...

Comment: You can speed this up a decent chunk by pushing all the FE calls into a single ``MathLink`CallFrontEnd``.

Comment: @b3m2a1: thanks for mentioning that. Have you actually tried that? I actually wouldn't know how to do that for the `While` loop. Or were you just thinking about combining the code before/after the loop and in its body?

Answer (score 3):

In case this is helpful to anyone stumbling upon this thread this as I did, here is simpler code to select all cells from the end of a notebook to the current evaluation cell.

```
endAtID = First @ EvaluationCell[];
SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], After, Notebook];
SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Previous, Cell];
While[
    SelectedCells[][[1, 1]] =!= endAtID,
    FrontEndTokenExecute[EvaluationNotebook[], "SelectPreviousLine"];
]
```

This can be modified to start from the cell containing the current insertion point, here is a button which will do this.

```
Button["press to select all cells from insertion point to end of notebook",
    SelectionMove[InputNotebook[], All, Cell];
    If[
        SelectedCells[InputNotebook[]] === {}, 
        SelectionMove[InputNotebook[], Next, Cell]
    ];
    endAtID = First @ SelectedCells[InputNotebook[]][[1]];
    SelectionMove[InputNotebook[], After, Notebook];
    SelectionMove[InputNotebook[], Previous, Cell];
    While[
        SelectedCells[InputNotebook[]][[1, 1]] =!= endAtID, 
        FrontEndTokenExecute[InputNotebook[], "SelectPreviousLine"];
    ]
]
```

The code inside the button above should work fine when triggered from a keyboard shortcut or palette button or wherever you want. To make it delete the selected cells, simply add

```
NotebookDelete[InputNotebook[]]
```

to the end of the code inside the button.

AMENDMENTS:
To make the selection go from the insertion point to the end of the notebook, you can modify the code as such

```
Button["press to select all cells from insertion point to end of notebook",
    SelectionMove[InputNotebook[], After, Notebook];
    SelectionMove[InputNotebook[], Previous, Cell];
    endAtID = First@SelectedCells[InputNotebook[]][[1]];
    SelectionMove[EvaluationCell[], All, Cell];
    While[
        SelectedCells[InputNotebook[]][[-1, 1]] =!= endAtID, 
        FrontEndTokenExecute[InputNotebook[], "SelectNextLine"];
    ]
]
```

I like [Albert Riley](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/169/albert-retey)'s suggestion in the comments to use FixedPoint so much I thought we should add it here

```
SelectionMove[InputNotebook[], All, Cell];
FixedPoint[
    (
        FrontEndTokenExecute[InputNotebook[], "SelectNextLine"];
        SelectedCells[InputNotebook[]]
    ) &,
    {}
]
```

Comment: very good find, turns out there is also a FrontEndToken "SelectNextLine" which would allow to select the rest of the notebook from top to bottom instead from bottom to top. Both seem to be quite useful, would you mind to share where you did find them?

Comment: Both would work indeed, you could move the selection to the end of the notebook and then select the previous cell and use a similar While loop. I found this front end token at the very end of the documentation for SelectionMove inside the "possible issues" subsection.

Comment: Thanks for the information about the source, not exacty where one would actively search, but at least it's there:-). But isn't what you describe in the comment what already is in your answer and the "SelectNextLine" would allow to select the current cell and then extend to the end of the notebook? Something like: `SelectionMove[InputNotebook[], All, Cell];
FixedPoint[(FrontEndTokenExecute[InputNotebook[], "SelectNextLine"]; SelectedCells[InputNotebook[]]) &,{}]`

Comment: Yes my comment is the same concept, but it did need some refactoring. I added the code to the answer along with highlighting your intelligent use of FixedPoint

Answer (score 2):

My take as I needed a solution I could just run in a cell or call from a pallete.

```
ClearAll[evaluateFromHere]
evaluateFromHere[
  HoldPattern[nb_NotebookObject : EvaluationNotebook[]]] :=
 Module[{},
  SelectionMove[nb, Previous, Cell, 1];
  If[
   SelectedCells[nb] == {},
   NotebookEvaluate[nb],
   Map[
     (SelectionMove[#, All, Cell];
       SelectionEvaluateCreateCell[nb];) &,
     NextCell[First@SelectedCells[nb], All]];
   ];
  ]
```

Comment: This is great! thanks for sharing