# How to use a shortcut to evaluate an expression without having it show in the notebook, using the KeyEventTranslations.tr?

Tags: front-end, keyboard

I'm trying to have a custom function evaluated via a keyboard shortcut, and add this shortcut via the `KeyEventTranslations.tr`.

As a test example I took the example provided in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16174/27539) to add and evaluate the expression `x=1` when pressing `ctrl+u`.

My only problem with that is that it leaves the `x=1` expression on the notebook, while I don't want to see it.
I therefore tried to delete it after evaluation, using the following:

```
Item[KeyEvent["u", Modifiers -> {Control}],
        FrontEndExecute[
          FrontEnd`SelectionMove[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[], After, Cell];
          FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[
            FrontEnd`InputNotebook[], 
            Cell[BoxData[RowBox[{"x", "=", "1"}]], "Input"]
          ];
          FrontEnd`SelectionMove[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[], Previous, Cell];
          FrontEnd`SelectionEvaluate[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[]];
          FrontEnd`SelectionMove[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[], Previous, CellGroup, 1];
          FrontEnd`NotebookDelete[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[]]
        ]
    ]
```

This is however not working for some reason.
It seems to work up to the delete line (even though I didn't manage to properly select the whole cell group).
When the last `NotebookDelete` line is added however, nothing seems to happen: the value of `x` is not changed at all and no expression is printer.

How can I modify this to have this toy expression (or any other expression) work in this way?

Of course, a way to just evaluate the expression without writing it in the notebook at all would be also appreciated!

Comment: Use `KernelExecute`. See for example what Rolf Mertig does [here](https://github.com/rolfmertig/Shortcuts/blob/master/Shortcuts/Shortcuts.m). If you need to work with a notebook but don't want it visible use ``FrontEnd`NotebookSuspendScreenUpdates`` like I do [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/154374/38205)

Comment: that is actually what I first tried to do! I must have gotten some detail wrong because now I tried it again following the examples in that package and it works, thanks! If you want to add a brief answer I'll accept it, otherwise I'll selfanswer this one.

Comment: @b3m2a1 by the way, do you know why my example didn't work?

Comment: Have at it. I *think* your issue is that you need to encapsulate that in a list. My copy of Mathematica is currently frozen but `FrontEndExecute` takes a list for multiple commands as it's not `Hold*` so that should have all evaluated out to ``FrontEnd`NotebookDelete[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[]]`` before being passed to `FrontEndExecute`.

Comment: @b3m2a1 I tried that but it still didn't work

Comment: Unclear to me then. One thing you might be interested in, just as an aside, is that you can move the selection to the written content with ``NotebookWrite``. That cuts out one selection move, so that's nice.

Comment: @b3m2a1 that is very nice indeed, I didn't notice that functionality, thanks!

Comment: At least somewhat related: [(680)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/680/121), [(29258)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29258/121)

Answer (score 1):

Following [`b3m2a1`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/38205/b3m2a1)'s advise, and the examples found in [this package](https://github.com/rolfmertig/Shortcuts/tree/master/Shortcuts), the answer is to use `KernelExecute` instead of front end functions.

I added the following to the `KeyEventTranslations.tr` file in (modify path according to your OS) `FileNameJoin@{$UserBaseDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "TextResources", "Windows"}`:

```
Item[KeyEvent["u", Modifiers -> {Control}],
    KernelExecute[
        x = 1 + 1
    ],
    MenuEvaluator -> Automatic
]
```

and it works as intended (after restarting the front end).